# What to do with SpamAssassin after installing Amavis?

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, amavis

As far as I know, `Amavis` has `SpamAssassin` on his own (I think Perl Mail::SpamAssassin).

Before installing `Amavis`, I was using `SpamAssassin` binary and daemon (`spamc` and `spamd`) plugged into MTA (Postfix via pipe).

My question is: what to do - is it safe to `apt-get remove spamassassin` now after installation and configuring of `Amavis`?

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Ubuntu 14.04 Server Guide [Mail Filtering](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mail-filtering.html):

> Amavisd-new is a wrapper program that can **call** any number of content
>   filtering programs for spam detection, antivirus, etc.

You still need SpamAssassin, so you **should not uninstall** it. Actually, [`amavisd-new-postfix`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amavisd-new-postfix) depends on [`spamassassin`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/spamassassin), so removing the package with `apt-get remove spamassassin` will also remove Amavis.

This chart visualizes *how the pieces fit together* (based on the same Mail Filtering guide):

[image: Ubuntu + Postfix + Amavisd]

You should

1. **remove the pipe** to SpamAssassin from your Postfix configuration, i.e. remove:

   ```
   smtp      inet  n      -      -      -      -      smtpd -o content_filter=spamfilter
   ```

   and

   ```
   spamassassin
        unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
        flags=R
        user=spamuser 
        argv=/usr/bin/spamc 
        -e /usr/sbin/sendmail 
        -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
   ```
2. **integrate Amavis to Postfix**, instead.

   > For Postfix integration, enter the following from a terminal prompt:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo postconf -e 'content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024'
   > ```
   >
   > Next edit /etc/postfix/master.cf and add the following to the end of
   >   the file:
   >
   > ```
   > smtp-amavis     unix    -       -       -       -       2       smtp
   >         -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
   >         -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
   >         -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
   >         -o max_use=20
   >
   > 127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
   >         -o content_filter=
   >         -o local_recipient_maps=
   >         -o relay_recipient_maps=
   >         -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
   >         -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
   >         -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   >         -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
   >         -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
   >         -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
   >         -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
   >         -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
   >         -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
   >         -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
   >         -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
   >         -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
   >         -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
   >         -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
   >         -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_milters
   > ```
   >
   > Also add the following two lines immediately below the "pickup"
   >   transport service:
   >
   > ```
   >  -o content_filter=
   >  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
   > ```

Comment: Thanks. But, do you think I should do something with configuration? Maybe to **restore params to default - or no**t? I think that conf files has my own, adjusted params, example: `rewrite_header Subject` `required_score 3.0` `use_bayes 1`

Comment: Since you were using Postfix to pipe messages to Spamassassin, it should use the same configuration when called by Amavisd. You probably don't need to change anything. Both will do spam filtering based on server-wide configuration from `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf`. In setups with `mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"` users have possibility to use Spamassassin independently with `:0fw \n | spamassassin` in their `.procmailrc`. This allows using custom settings in `.spamassassin/user_prefs`, which this Amavisd setup naturally omits.